# How to get output redirect as parameter in bash?

Tags: bash, parameters, output, io-redirection

I would like to know if it's possible to get the output redirection file name as a parameter in bash?

For example :

```
./myscript.sh parameter1 > outputfile
```

Is there a way to get "outputfile" as a parameter like $2? In my script I have to do few operations in outputfile but I don't know which file I have to update... The second problem is, this script is already running and used by several tasks so I cannot change the user input...

Best regards

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. A script can certainly redirect to a file whose name is given as a parameter, as in `doSomething > $2; andSomeMore -foo $1 >> $2`.

Comment: What kinds of operations do you have to do? If you manipulate the file directly, that's likely to conflict with the ordinary output that's being written to `stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

Redirections are not parameters to the program. When a program's output is redirected, the shell opens the file and connects file descriptor `2` to it before running the program. The program then simply writes to fd 2 (aka `stdout`) and it goes to the file.

On Linux and similar systems you can use `/dev/stdout`, which is a symbolic link to the process's stdout file.